# Pandas: How to sum second level columns in hierarchical dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, hierarchical-data

I have a DataFrame that looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,4,5,1,2], [7,8,10,11,7,8], [13,14,16,17,4,5]], index=pd.date_range('2004-01-01', '2004-01-03'))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x', 'y', 'z'], list('ab')])
df
             x       y       z     
             a   b   a   b   a  b  
2004-01-01   1   2   4   5   1  2  
2004-01-02   7   8   10  11  7  8  
2004-01-03  13  14   16  17  4  5
```

I would like to sum the second level columns (a+b) for each first level column and have the first level columns as column names

Answer (score 6):

You can specify `level` and `axis` parameter in groupby to aggregate by level 0 of the column index (`axis=1`):

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()

             x   y   z
2004-01-01   3   9   3
2004-01-02  15  21  15
2004-01-03  27  33   9
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! And what if I want to subtract (b-a) and have the first level columns as column names?

Comment: You can try `df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'b')].droplevel(1, 1) - df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'a')].droplevel(1, 1)` `.loc[:, (slice(None), 'b')]` gets column `b` and `droplevel` removes the 2nd level column index, and then `subtract` directly.